# What processor should I choose?

Tags: laptop, processor

I am planning to buy a laptop. I have selected two . [One has a 8th generation 1.80GHz core i7 processor](https://ryanscomputers.com/asus-s510un-intel-intel-core-i7-8550u-1-80ghz-8gb-ddr4-128gb-ssd-1tb-radeon-mx150-2gb-graphics-15-6-inch-win-10-home-gold-metal-notebook.html#tab-product-view2)  and [other has 7th generation 2.70 Ghz core i7 processor](https://ryanscomputers.com/asus-k401uq-intel-core-i7-14-inch-gray-metal-notebook.html#tab-product-view2). Shall I emphasize on clock speed or generation?

I am going to use linux OS. Most of the time I will work on android studio and py charm and spyder for machine learning stuff.

Comment: the 8th Gen i7 will probably go to the same turbo clocks as the 7th Gen one but also has two more physical cores, which probably will be much more handy...

Comment: Software development typically benefits from more cores even if slightly slower, and as much RAM as you can afford.